# Migrate from Eclipse+ADT plugin to android studio with gradle

Tags: android, adt

Im looking for a way to migrate my project from Eclipse+ADT plugin to Android Studio.

Is there any tutorial for this ? or i can just open the project normally in Android Studio?

plus i want to add my project to gradle in andorid studio.

also there is Caution in google site for using "early access preview" product.

is there any cons or pros for this migration ?

or should i stick to eclipse?

the project im building is getting bigger and bigger and its kinda hard to open it in eclipse(slow loading). even the clean process takes about 10-15 second.

Is it Worse or worst to do this procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Android for .NET Developers: 1 Getting Started

2 - Android for .NET Developers: 2 Building Apps With Android Studio

3 - Android for .NET Developers: 3 Adopting The Android Mindset

4 - Android for .NET Developers: 4 Understanding The Android Platform

At [Pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses#android) above 4 is a series of tutorials. All these four tutorials use Android Studio. And during these tutorials instructor explains about many features of Android Studio.

Comment: thanks for respond. it goes for my first question i guess -> "using android studio instead of eclipse" . can u help me with other ones too ?

Comment: I have not come across any developer who is using Android Studio for such a large projects where eclipse starts to fail. However, the instructor of above courses is very experienced. And he is using Android Studio now a days. May be he can help you. you can reach him at 

**Twitter**
https://twitter.com/HedgehogJim

**Blog**
http://hedgehogjim.wordpress.com/

**LinedIn**
http://www.linkedin.com/pub/jim-wilson/3/b02/130

**Website**
http://jwhh.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Android Studio 0.4.2 or later, the best way to import an Eclipse project is to import it into Android Studio; it will make a copy of the project, rearrange its directory structure to something more suitable for Gradle-based projects, and set up the Gradle build files for you.

There is documentation that recommends that you export your project from Eclipse to a Gradle-based export. That documentation is based on older versions of Android Studio not having direct import, and the documentation is out of date. What's more, that export specifies old versions of the Android Gradle plugin in its export, which you'd need to fix up manually. For those reasons it's better to use the new method of direct import.